# Product of two functions a function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

For some f to be a function, then for every $x$ in the domain of $f$, there should be unique image of $x$ in the range of $f$.

$f(x_1) \neq f(x_2) \implies x_1 \neq x_2 \\x_1 = x_2 \implies f(x_1)=f(x_2)$

Say $f(x)g(y)$ is the product of 2 functions. For this product to be again a function

$x_1y_1 = x_2y_2 \implies f(x_1)g(y_1) = f(x_2)g(y_2) $?

How to prove or disprove this? I am not able to get any clue. Please enlighten

Comment: It is not true, so you could find a counterexample.

Comment: Are you sure you want to consider $f(x)g(y)$ as a two-variable function?

Comment: $(x,y)\mapsto f(x)g(y)$ is the tensor product $f\otimes g$, not the *actual* product $f\times g:x\mapsto f(x)g(x)$.

Comment: @Henry sir, i thought of ths example to falsify my claim. $f(x) = x, g(y)=y^2$ and taking points(2,3) and (3,2) for (x,y). This disproves. Actually i got doubt when i was thinking about whther $x_1*x_2$(product of 2 random variables) is a random variable given $x_1$, $x_2$ are 2 different random variables. Please explain.

Comment: A product of two functions would be $f(x)g(x)$.

Comment: Hmm, product function defines on point wise product like (fg)(x)=f(x)g(x). So if you want to prove or disprove f(x)g(y) a function or not (for two different independent variables), it doesn't mean anything!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prove that $(x,y)\mapsto f(x)g(y)$ is a function, then $$x_1y_1 = x_2y_2 \implies f(x_1)g(y_1) = f(x_2)g(y_2)$$
is a wrong thing to look at. Instead, you need to prove that $$(x_1,y_1) = (x_2,y_2) \implies f(x_1)g(y_1) = f(x_2)g(y_2).$$
Therefore, assume $(x_1,y_1) = (x_2,y_2)$. Then $x_1 = x_2$ and $y_1 = y_2$. Since $f$ and $g$ are functions, it follows that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ and $g(y_1) = g(y_2)$. Finally,
$$\left.\begin{align}f(x_1) = f(x_2) \implies f(x_1)g(y_1) = f(x_2)g(y_1) \\
g(y_1) = g(y_2) \implies f(x_2)g(y_1) = f(x_2)g(y_2)
\end{align}\right\}\implies f(x_1)g(y_1)=f(x_2)g(y_2).$$

If you want to prove that $x\mapsto f(x)g(x)$ is a function, do the same thing, but replace $y$'s with $x$'s.